How many square matrices have at least one square sub-matrix where the elements neighboring the sub-matrix are 1 or the edge of the matrix?
I'm trying to count this problem, but I keep over counting it. A binary 4 by 4 matrix has $2^{16}$ possible combinations. If this matrix has a square sub-matrix where the neighbors are bounded by 1s or the border of the matrix, then I want to include it in the count. I'm not trying to count how many sub-matrices have this property.
$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
In this example, matrix $A$ has this property twice. There's a sub-matrix of size 1 by 1 in the upper right corner bounded by the top and left edge. Similarly, there's a 3x3 matrix bounded by all 1s on the top and left sides and bounded by the right and bottom edge. It doesn't matter what is inside the sub-matrix.
$$B=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
For example, in matrix $B$ those same sub-matrices are filled in with some 1s but it doesn't change the fact that this matrix would still be counted. I've tried but I keep over counting even in simple cases.
$$C=\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
This is how I'm trying to do it. Let's say we have matrix $C$. I think in this case, there are $2^{25-2}$ combinations. There would be 4 like this so $4(2^{23})$. But that's $2^{25}$ so I'm already over counting. I was going to continue by moving to the next column like this.
$$D=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
There would be 8 of these, 2 on each side. I feel like I'm on the right track with this approach. It's not too hard to enumerate these even if I'm not thinking about them in the right way.
And by the way, I'm only doing 4x4 for illustration purposes. I would like to know this for any size matrix. If that's too complicated, 5x5 and 6x6 would be enough.

For small $n$ (say $n\le 6$), a brute force count (via a computer program) is feasible. Do you have reason to believe that you can do better than brute force?

I've already brute forced it but I don't know if it's right.

What were your brute force results?

For a 5x5, I'm getting $30,746,821$ that have this property leaving me with $2,807,611$ that do.

For $n=5$, I also got $30746821$.

As stated, the answer is uncountable. Clearly you are assuming the matrix consists of just $1$s and $0$s, but you never gave such a condition. Instead of counting how many matrices meet your condition, try counting how many matrices do not meet it. Then subtract that result from $2^{16}$. Then you do not need to worry about overcounting due to matrices having multiples conforming submatrices.
